# Two "Good to meet you" in the movie "Ex Machina"

Tags: pronunciation

[image: "Ex Machina"].

Two actors say the same script ["It's good to meet you"](https://youtu.be/FBZFgGb21Go?t=22) in the movie trailer "Ex Machina".

I think there's difference of two sayings in pronunciation.

> First, an employee "It's ***good/ to*** ***meet/ you***, Nathan." (/ means not-linking)
>
> Second, the CEO "It's ***'goodo'*** ***'meechu'*** too, Caleb." ('words' from my listening)

I feel

- These ***"good/ to"*** and ***"meet/ you"*** imply decency and formality.
- Those ***"goodo"*** and ***"meechu"*** imply frankness, friendship, a little bit arrogance.

How do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second simply comes from having a different dialect/manner of speech where the words are slightly slurred together or not enunciated. While it can indicate less formality, by itself it doesn't indicate other things, like friendship or arrogance - that comes from the character and his tone.

There is a small difference between your examples, but you may be reading too much into it.